# form_tag rails with method: :get and multipart: true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i'm using a from_tag with multipart for pass a file, when i use post method works perfectly, but if i change the method to get the param only pass the filename as string.

```
<%= form_tag receptors_overview_path, method: :get, multipart: true do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :receptors_file, accept: '.xlsx' %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Import!', class: "btn btn-success"  %>
<% end %>
```

Routes

```
get 'receptors/overview'
```

It's posible to work multipart with get method? or only works with post method.
thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a bold stand here and say that you can't use multipart and GET together. The file contents from a multipart form would be carried in the entity, which need a body that GET doesn't have.

There are server-side tricks you could use to fake the method type to interpret a POST as a GET, perhaps, or you could serialize the upload client-side and pass the contents as a parameter using a Javascript library, but just a vanilla HTML form can't (and shouldn't) do multipart and GET.